# Javascript array object copy merge

Tags: javascript, node.js

## There are now two arrays

**The first array：**

```
var arr = [
   {path: '/a', name: 'aa'},
   {path: '/f', name: 'ff'}
];
```

**Two arrays:**

```
var arr1 = [
   {path: '/a', meta: {title:'aa2', hidden: 1}},
   {path: '/b', meta: {title:'bb', hidden: 1}},
   {path: '/c', meta: {title:'cc', hidden: 0}},
   {path: '', meta: {title:'dd', hidden: 0}}
   {path: '', meta: {title:'ee', hidden: 0}}
 ]
```

**I want to merge them into this:**

```js
var arr2 = [
  {path: '/a', name: 'aa', meta: {title:'aa2', hidden: 1}},
  {path: '/b', meta: {title:'bb', hidden: 1}},
  {path: '/c', meta: {title:'cc', hidden: 0}},
  {path: '', meta: {title:'dd', hidden: 0}},
  {path: '', meta: {title:'ee', hidden: 0}},
  {path: '/f', name: 'ff'}
]
console.log(arr2)
```

What should I do to get an array of arr2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge both the array into one and than use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

**Here idea is-**

- First merge both the arrays into a single array
- Now loop through merged array and use path as key
- If key already exists on object than merge previous value with current value
- Else assign a new value
- Finally takes the values out of object to get desired output

```js
var arr = [{path: '', meta: {title: 'index'}},{path: '/a', name: 'aa'}];

var arr1 = [{path: '/a', meta: {title:'aa2', hidden: 1}}, {path: '/b', meta: {title:'bb', hidden: 1}} ]  
   
let op = [...arr,...arr1].reduce((op,inp) => {
  let path = inp.path
  op[path] = op[path] || {}
  op[path] = {...op[path], ...inp}
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

UPDATE

```js
var arr = [
 {path: '/a', name: 'aa'},
 {path: '/f', name: 'ff'}
];

var arr1 = [
 {path: '/a', meta: {title:'aa2', hidden: 1}},
 {path: '/b', meta: {title:'bb', hidden: 1}},
 {path: '/c', meta: {title:'cc', hidden: 0}},
 {path: '', meta: {title:'dd', hidden: 0}},
 {path: '', meta: {title:'ee', hidden: 0}}
]

let toBeMerged = arr.reduce((op,inp)=> (op[inp.path] = inp, op),{})

let final = arr1.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  if(toBeMerged[inp.path]){
    op.push({...inp,...toBeMerged[inp.path]})
  } else{
    op.push(inp)
  }
  return op
},[])

Object.entries(toBeMerged).forEach(([key,value])=>{
  let found = final.find(({path})=> path === key )
  if(!found){
    final.push(value)
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I just tried it. If there are multiple empty paths in the first array, it seems to filter out.
var arr = [{path: '', meta: {title: 'index'}},{path: '/a', name: 'aa'},{path: '', meta: {title: 'index2'}}]

Comment: @25757750 you should add a proper description on what basis you want to merge, with your initial data i felt like if path is same merge them, will you explain on what condition you're merging them ?

Comment: If the path to arr does not exist in the arr1 element, add it, otherwise merge the elements

Comment: @25757750 will the paths in `arr` are always going to be unique ?